# Add childs and siblings to KnpMenuBundle

Tags: php, symfony, knpmenubundle

For my app I am creating a menu. The goal is:

- Having a main menu in the major AppBundle
- Other bundles shalll be able to extend the main menu (adding childs and siblings)

It should feel like a plugin architecture on bundle basis. On the IRC someone suggested using the KnpMenuBundle so I tried that out. Now I am stuck because I could not find a way to extend the main menu in other bundles.

What is necessary within a new bundle to add children to the main menu?

This is the menu and services I created so far:

```
services:
  app.menu_builder:
    class: AppBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
    arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory"]

  app.main_menu:
    class: Knp\Menu\MenuItem
    factory: ["@app.menu_builder", createMainMenu]
    arguments: ["@request_stack"]
    tags:
      - { name: knp_menu.menu, alias: main }
```

The Menu Builder:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Menu;


use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class MenuBuilder
{
    private $factory;

    public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public function createMainMenu(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');
        $menu->setDisplay(false);

        return $menu;
    }
}
```

A new AcmeBundle shall now be able to extend the main menu. Like adding children to the "root". How to achieve that?

Please let me know if you need more code.

Comment: Did you read http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/events.html

Comment: Rofl ^^ The guy in the IRC said, that other bundles can add menu items via YML. And that it will be generated only once.